# How do I merge sort characters?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to merge sort characters. Whenever I enter an array of character, the last element of the array remains unidentified/unrecognized.

How can I fix my program?

```
void Merge(char *array, int left, int mid, int right) {

  char tempArray[right-left+1];
  int pos = 0, lpos = left, rpos = mid + 1;

  while (lpos <= mid && rpos <= right) {
    if (array[lpos] <= array[rpos]) {
      tempArray[pos++] = array[lpos++];
    } else {
      tempArray[pos++] = array[rpos++];
    }
  }

  while (lpos <= mid)
    tempArray[pos++] = array[lpos++];
  while (rpos <= right)
    tempArray[pos++] = array[rpos++];

  int iter;
  for (iter = 0; iter < pos; iter++) {
    array[iter+left] = tempArray[iter];
  }

  return;
}

void MergeSort(char *array, int left, int right) {
  int mid = (left + right) / 2;

  if (left < right) {
    MergeSort(array, left, mid);
    MergeSort(array, mid + 1, right);
    Merge(array, left, mid, right);
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program seems correct.  Are you sure you are calling it with the correct bounds?  For example:

```
MergeSort(str, 0, strlen(str)-1);
```